# Bean utils with property change listeners dynamic addition?

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils, changelistener, propertychangelistener

`Commons Beanutils` library contains good methods to operate on beans in runtime. But strangely I can find any methods to operate with change listeners.

I.e. I can set some property in underlying bean with [`WrapDynaBean`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/WrapDynaBean.html), but I can't add listener for this property change.

Is it true? Why?

Ans is there any library which fulfills this gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example I found is JGoodies Binding from here: http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/